# Karate: Master node unable to communicate with worker node and getting Connection refused error

Tags: docker, networking, karate, docker-network, distributed-testing

[Windows 10 and MAC] Trying to run karate test case on docker with Distributed-Testing, but not working as expected and getting below error on worker node.

Error:

```
21:34:34.263 [main]  ERROR com.intuit.karate - org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to karate:9080 [karate/172.18.0.2] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused), http call failed after 3 milliseconds for url: http://karate:9080/healthcheck

21:34:36.266 [main]  DEBUG com.intuit.karate.shell.Command - attempt #30 waiting for http to be ready at: http://karate:9080/healthcheck

21:34:36.270 [main]  DEBUG com.intuit.karate - request:

31 > GET http://karate:9080/healthcheck

31 > Host: karate:9080

31 > Connection: Keep-Alive

31 > User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/1.8.0_275)

31 > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
```

Ref Link:
[Distributed-Testing] https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/Distributed-Testing

Using jobserver example project mentioned on above website. https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/examples/jobserver

Commands Used:

```
docker run --network=karate --name karate --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN -w /src karate bash mvn clean test -Dtest=WebDockerJobRunner
```

```
docker run -d --network=karate --rm --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN -e KARATE_JOBURL=http://karate:9080 karate
```

Comment: clearly the URL is not working. I suggest you work with someone who knows Docker and networking on whatever OS you are using. no one else will be able to help. you are also welcome to contribute code